# Network tab is not showing the css applied on the selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am new in markup languages and I am facing issue while applying my first css file to my index.html. Here is how I used link tag in html file[css file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eedXq.png):
index.html code

I checked network tab in developer tools, css file is loading but when I click on any particular tag to see its styles, it not showing there. I am adding css file and network tab screen-shot below:
Network tab not showing the applied css

Comment: First thing is, your CSS is not valid, kindly read about CSS then start using. Second thing is, Network tab doesn't show CSS, Elements tab shows.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have imported the css file in index.html. (I guess you should've because its showing in network tab)
2. Check in the developer tools > Elements. Click on the arrow pointer on left side of the Elements tab beside Toggle Device toolbar. Or press Ctrl + Shift + C. Now hover over the elements you assigned your styles to.
3. Also when you hover, click one element and check if the styles are applied on the right side of the Elements tab in the Styles section in dev tools. Find your element and check if the styles you defined are applied.
4. if thid doesn't work, check in the same Styles tab if the styles you defined are being overridden by some other styles.

Answer (score 0):

```css
h1:{
    color: red;
}
```

So, that is not a valid CSS code. Instead you should right something like this:

```css
h1{
    color: blue;
}
h1:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

That is the example of normal and hover state. Hope that will solve the problem.